# How to make this script for sending canned responses in Gmail to work?

Tags: gmail, google-apps-script, gmail-canned-response

The following script is supposed to use to send automatic response emails using Gmail's canned response feature while avoiding “+canned.response” added to the username in the reply:

```
function RespondEmail(e) {

      // set response mail
      var response = GmailApp.getMessageById('153c2b9e7d4ac8c4');
      var responsebody = response.getBody();

      //send response email
      var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases()
      var threads = GmailApp.search("label:respondemail label:unread");
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].reply("", {htmlBody: responsebody, from: aliases[0]});}

      // mark all as read
      var threads = GmailApp.search("label:respondemail label:unread");
      GmailApp.markThreadsRead(threads);
    }
```

The script can be set to search for emails by setting a time based interval trigger. If an email with the label `respondemail` is found, which could have been assigned to it through the Gmail filter feature, an automatic answer will be sent.

However, no alias is picked up (`aliases` is just an empty string). It works inserting an email address instead of this string, though. Is it possible to have your name shown as sender, instead of just your email address, which will happen when you send an email manually?

Comment: Do you have an email message with Id `1452e6aef2c5c09f` ? To get the Id of a message that is the  first in a thread, open it in Gmail: the Id is the part at the end of URL, after `/#inbox/`

Comment: No, I fixed it now, thanks! However, another problem showed up, see the last paragraph above.

Answer (score -1):

Solved completely! I had to use the name parameter as well:

```
threads[i].reply("", {htmlBody: responsebody, from: 'someone@gmail.com', name: 'Someone Blabla'});}
```